# Sweetalert 2 JS is not working properly in small devices

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a SweetAlert2 the alert popups, in the desktop version coming fine but in mobile/ small devices is not working properly

```
    Swal.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title:  response.data.body.Data[0].status_text,
                timer: 3500
             })
```

Desktop version:

[image]

Mobile Version:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue I spent more than a day for this.

Comment: Can you clarify which mobile / browser you are using? Also do you have the same issue on the examples at https://sweetalert2.github.io?

Comment: @G.Verni Just I'm checking in the Google Chrome Inspect element and tested all small devices. Nokia 6.1 Plus Mobile Google Chrome for Android browser also same issue.

Comment: kishore can you try the samples at sweetalert2.github.io? I tried all of them on my phones and none shows the same behavior. I’m wondering if your page has a css that mess up with swal graphics. Please try those examples and report back

Comment: @G.Verni Yes I'm using sweetalert2.github.io I tried their a demo in www.sweetalert2.github.io its working fine but in our project is not working in small devices

Comment: @G.Verni we're using this  `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.0.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>`

Comment: if it’s working fine with the example on sweetalert.github.io then you need to figure out what you do in your page that messes up the CSS of sweetalert

Comment: @G.Verni thanks for the update we're not added any CSS files of sweetalert2 we just using this JS CDN `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.0.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>`

Comment: you need look at other styles you are applying to your page (either inline or css) besides the sweetalert ones. If you can share a live example i can try to help you. Without that it’s impossible

Answer (score 0):

Try to change into `icon` instead of `type` :)

```
 Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title:  response.data.body.Data[0].status_text,
            timer: 3500
 });
```