# Sweet Alert 2 Icon Does Not Render Properly

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I'm trying to create a modal that pops up when the webpage loads. The modal opens as expected but the icon and the animation do not render properly. My code snippets are from the website [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

```html
<!-- import the sweet alert 2 package from cdn link -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<!-- sample from the sweet alert github website -->
<script>
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'error',
    title: 'Oops...',
    text: 'Something went wrong!',
    footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
  })
</script>
```

When I run the code, the modal that is produced renders a faulty icon as shown below:

[image: Faulty icon modal before fix]

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723741/sweetalert-2-js-is-not-working-properly-in-small-devices) question, I tried changing the `icon` property with `type`, as shown below:

```html
<!-- sample from the sweet alert github website with type instead of icon -->
<script>
  Swal.fire({
    type: 'error',
    title: 'Oops...',
    text: 'Something went wrong!',
    footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
  })
</script>
```

The result of running this code is shown below:

[image: Faulty icon rendering after fix]

This code does not render the icon at all. I am using SweetAlert2 and a macOS operating system. How can I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Probably a CSS problem - try manually modifying styles for `.swal2-x-mark-line-left` and `.swal2-x-mark-line-right` - modify if necessary: `width`, `height`, `top`, `left`, `right`, etc.

Comment: Should I change the version of SweetAlert when importing?

Comment: I tried your code on my PC using Chrome and it all looks OK, so it's probably your device/browser ... If that is the case add some CSS to target problematic devices/browsers and fix those issues

Comment: have you tried actually including the stylesheet https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage

Answer (score 1):

Span error!
Since you gave a generic font-size for the span tag, icon corruption occurs. If you remove it from the css part, this problem will be resolved